# VB.NET Windows Forms DataGridView: How to alternate a column in DatagridView between TextBox and DropDownList

Tags: windows, vb.net, forms, datagridview

Have a datagridview that I want to populate a column with either a text box or a combo box based on a value in the generic list. Please see attached image. I need one cell in one row to display a drop-down list and on the next row with the same "Grouping" I need an editable textbox in the same column.

Does anyone have an example of how to accomplish this request?  I appreciate any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOUHS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYnoZ.png)